# Filtering Child Object with Multiple Criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm having an issue filtering records returned using linq. The objects involved look like this:

**Appointment**

```
public partial class Appointment
{
    public Appointment()
    {
        Callbacks = new HashSet<Callback>();
    }

    [Key()]
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Callback> Callbacks { get; set; }
}
```

**Callback**

```
public partial class Callback
{
    [Key()]
    public int CallbackId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }

    public virtual User AssignedTo { get; set; }
}
```

**User**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Callbacks = new HashSet<Callback>();
    }

    [Key()]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Ref { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Callback> Callbacks { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to return records that meet the following criteria:

- The appointment `start` date must equal `searchDate`
- The appointment is not deleted
- The appointment `start` date must not clash with any appointments that the user already has

I've tried using the following query, but no results are returned (there are appointments available for the date `01/03/2016` (`dd/mm/yyyy`).

```
public List<AppointmentSearchResultsViewModel> SearchByDate(DateTime searchDate, string userName)
{
    return _context.Appointments
        .Where(a =>
            a.Start.Date == searchDate
            && a.Deleted == null
            && a.Callbacks.Any(c =>
                !(c.Appointment.Start != a.Start
                && c.AssignedTo.Ref == userName
                && c.Deleted == null)
        ))
        .OrderBy(a => a.Start)
        .Select(a)
        .ToList();
}
```

Could anyone help me with how to filter correctly based on the criteria above?

**Edit**

To try and clarify the model:

- A user has callbacks

  - A callback has an appointment

The aim of this query is to search for all appointments on the `searchDate` where the user does not already have a callback scheduled for the appointment time.

Comment: Your model and your code does not match. So it is unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to filter Callbacks or Appointments? How does this Linq compile?

Comment: You are saying "The appointment start date must equal searchDate" and then you are saying "The appointment start date must not clash with any appointments that the user already has". How come ?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Means that `searchdate` has not already been added to any users appointment.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I've updated the question to try and clarify the intention of the query and how the model works.

Comment: I wrote an aswer, but it would be nice for others to see some sample data to understand what you are trying to do. Querying over callbacks might be a redundant operation.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Would it be of use if I posted a pure SQL query that would do what I wanted?

Comment: Yes certainly. A working SQL would help understanding and would even be nicer if some table style sample data included :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a negative comparison for your `Any`-statement:

```
!a.Callbacks.Any(c =>
    (c.Appointment.Start == a.Start
    && c.AssignedTo.Ref == userName
    && c.Deleted == null)
```

Thus you only got those `Callbacks` from `a.Callbacks` which have a different `Start`-date.

Furtheremore you can ommit the `Select(a)`-statement at the end and immediately call `ToList`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks, this did it.

Answer (score 1):

The model and what you are trying to achieve is not really clear to me, but I will try my chances anyway on the part O could understand:

```
  return _context.Appointments
      .Where(a =>
          a.Start.Date == searchDate
          && a.Deleted == null
          && !a.Callbacks.Any(c =>
              (c.Appointment.Start == a.Start
              && c.AssignedTo.Ref == userName
              && c.Deleted == null)
      ))
      .OrderBy(a => a.Start)
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know what you get in return...

```
return context.Users.Where(user => user.Ref = userName)
                    .SelectMany(user => user.Callbacks)
                    .Where(cb => cb.Appointment.Deleted == null)
                    .Where(cb => cb.Appointment.Start == searchDate)
                    .Select(cb => cb.Appointment)
                    .ToList();
```

This should return any appointments that clash with the `searchDate` parameter

Comment: This won´t filter those callbacks out whose start does NOT equal the one of the current entity (see the "clash-condition")

Comment: @HimBromBeere there is no current entity... Essentially he's asking how to find out if the user has any appointments at the given date, or have I missed something

Comment: OP is asking ro appointments for a given date that have not alreay been added to any user. You miss this last point I think. Btw: there is no `Users`-property within `context`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, but surely that can't be right, he's specifying a userName parameter, he also writes this in the description `The appointment start date must not clash with any appointments that the user already has`

Comment: @AydinAdn, yes that is why I thought querying callbacks might be redundant. It looks like nobody has a clear idea on it yet :)